# Как подсчитать статистику уникальных слов?

Tags: java

Задание: Скачать HTML страницу, с помощью списка разделителей подсчитать количество уникальных слов и вывести статистику в консоль.

Скачал страницу с помощью библиотеки Jsoup, список создал, но как действовать теперь не знаю.

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Parser {
    private static Document getPage() throws IOException {
        String url = "https://yandex.ru/";
        Document page = Jsoup.parse(new URL(url), 3000);
        return page;

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ArrayList<String> listOfSeparators = new ArrayList<String>();
        listOfSeparators.add(" ");
        listOfSeparators.add(",");
        listOfSeparators.add(".");
        listOfSeparators.add("!");
        listOfSeparators.add("?");
        listOfSeparators.add("(");
        listOfSeparators.add(")");
        listOfSeparators.add("[");
        listOfSeparators.add("]");
        listOfSeparators.add("-");
        listOfSeparators.add(";");
        listOfSeparators.add(":");
        listOfSeparators.add("\n");
        listOfSeparators.add("\r");
        listOfSeparators.add("\t");
        System.out.println(getPage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Самый простой вариант - разбить текст по разделителям и поместить их set. В set добавятся только уникальные слова.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Немного изменённый код, приведенный когда-то [JonasCz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4428462/jonascz) на англоязычном SO

Суть в том, чтобы документ преобразовать в `String`, по разделителям разделить документ на слова и записывать их в `HashMap` с учетом уже существующих и подсчетом количества.

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.*;


public class Parser {
    private static Document getPage() throws IOException {
        String url = "https://jsoup.org";
        Document page = Jsoup.parse(new URL(url), 3000);
        return page;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ArrayList<String> listOfSeparators = new ArrayList<String>();
        listOfSeparators.add(" ");
        listOfSeparators.add(",");
        listOfSeparators.add(".");
        listOfSeparators.add("!");
        listOfSeparators.add("?");
        listOfSeparators.add("(");
        listOfSeparators.add(")");
        listOfSeparators.add("[");
        listOfSeparators.add("]");
        listOfSeparators.add("-");
        listOfSeparators.add(";");
        listOfSeparators.add(":");
        listOfSeparators.add("\n");
        listOfSeparators.add("\r");
        listOfSeparators.add("\t");
        //System.out.println(getPage());
        
        String pagetext = getPage().text();
        String separatorsString = String.join("|\\", listOfSeparators);
        Map<String, Word> countMap = new HashMap<String, Word>();
        
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(pagetext.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))));
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] words = line.split(separatorsString);
            for (String word : words) {
                if ("".equals(word)) {
                    continue;
                }

                Word wordObj = countMap.get(word);
                if (wordObj == null) {
                    wordObj = new Word();
                    wordObj.word = word;
                    wordObj.count = 0;
                    countMap.put(word, wordObj);
                }

                wordObj.count++;
            }
        }

        reader.close();

        SortedSet<Word> sortedWords = new TreeSet<Word>(countMap.values());
      
        for (Word word : sortedWords) {
            System.out.println(word.count + "\t" + word.word);
        }
    }
        public static class Word implements Comparable<Word> {
            String word;
            int count;

            @Override
            public int hashCode() { return word.hashCode(); }

            @Override
            public boolean equals(Object obj) { return word.equals(((Word)obj).word); }

            @Override
            public int compareTo(Word b) { return b.count - count; }
        }
}
```

Проверить на `https://yandex.ru/` не могу, так как он заблокирован, поэтому протестировала на `https://jsoup.org`.

Результат:

```
19  the
17  a
15  and
14  HTML
11  to
9   of
7   from
6   DOM
5   source
4   Document
3   you
2   using
1   Parse
```

Comment: Работает, но почему он не все слова считает?

Comment: `Document.text` возвращает только текст, без html-разметки. Не было указано, какой текст брать, я для примера сделала так. Вы можете выбрать любую часть страницы, больше информации об этом и о методах, которые можно использовать в этом случае, [здесь](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Document.html#text(java.lang.String))

Comment: Большое Вам спасибо!